# Docker build seems to not see requirements.txt even though it's in same directory

Tags: python, django, docker, gunicorn, docker-build

I'm setting up a website, I have the backend set up using Django and Gunicorn, and I am trying to package the whole thing in a docker container. I am using docker `17.05.0-ce` edge on Ubuntu 17.04 Zesty. For some reason, even though the directory `mysite` has the `Dockerfile`, Django app, `requirements.txt`, `start.sh` ([on github here](https://github.com/HarryCaveMan/site-test/tree/master/mysite)), the docker build stops at `ADD requirements.txt /app/src/requirements.txt`.

```
# Dockerfile

# FROM base image to build upon
FROM phusion/baseimage

# RUN install python and pip
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python python-pip python-dev 

# ADD requirements.txt and RUN pip to install them
ADD requirements.txt /app/src/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app/src
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# EXPOSE port 8000 to allow communication to/from server
EXPOSE 8000

# CMD execute start.sh to start the server running.

WORKDIR /app/src/mysite
CMD ["/start.sh"]
# done!
```

I navigate to 'mysite', run `docker build - < Dockerfile` and it stops on the line where it copies `requirements.txt` and i get the following error:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/9 : FROM phusion/baseimage
 ---> 877509368a8d
Step 2/9 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> adcb4b9e8b08
Step 3/9 : RUN apt-get install -y python python-pip python-dev
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8dbbd3e010d5
Step 4/9 : ADD requirements.txt /app/src/requirements.txt
lstat requirements.txt: no such file or directory
```

Which, to me, says that I'm doing this all wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not sending a context to the docker daemon to build your project.

Use this:

```
docker build -t invent_an_image_name /path/to/mysite
```

Comment: should I do that from the same directory or can I do that from the derectory that contains `mysite`?

Comment: Sure. You can `docker build /path/to/mysite'. Try it and tell me

Comment: This seemed to work, what will the default name of the container when I go to run it?

Comment: You ask for the name of the image. It's an I'd that is returned in the build output. But put something better: `docker build -t invent_a_name /path/to/mysite`, then do docker run with that name. I will update my answer

Comment: This solved my problem, as a side note, when the machine runs it cannot find `start.sh`, is there something wrong with the way I set the working directory in my `Dockerfile` before `CMD ["/start.sh"]`? Or should I open another question for this...

Comment: I just copied `start.sh` into its own dir within the container in the `Dockerfile` I'll edit above soon.

Comment: Yes, but now no staticfiles. To avoid lengthy comments, I started a new question with the new dockerfile [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44401672/gunicorn-cant-find-staticfiles-after-dockerization).