# Gunicorn can't find staticfiles after dockerization

Tags: python, django, docker, dockerfile, gunicorn

I am using docker 17.05.0-cs edge on Ubuntu 17.04 Zesty. I have a gunicorn/Django app that I built [here](https://github.com/HarryCaveMan/site-test/tree/master/mysite). It runs fine before being dockerized, but gunicorn can't see the staticfiles after `docker build`. Here is the `Dockerfile`:

```
# Dockerfile

# FROM base image to build upon
FROM phusion/baseimage

# RUN install python and pip
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python python-pip python-dev 

# ENV set environment directory tree
ENV PROJECT=mysite
ENV CONTAINER_HOME=/opt
ENV CONTAINER_PROJECT=$CONTAINER_HOME/$PROJECT

# move to project WORKDIR
WORKDIR $CONTAINER_PROJECT

# COPY project to container directory
COPY . $CONTAINER_PROJECT

# RUN pip and install requirements
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


# COPY start.sh into known container location 
COPY start.sh /start.sh

# EXPOSE port 8000 to allow communication to/from server
EXPOSE 8000

# CMD execute start.sh to start the server running.
CMD ["/start.sh"]
# done!
```

The app runs and displays the page, funny, it even applies the `css` templates while saying it can't find `bootstrap.css` or `bootstrap.js`. It does not execute the script to toggle the menu though. The current templates are just an artifact of my initial build, the new ones won't even use `bootstrap.js` I'm pretty sure. It runs but the toggle doesn't work which I know is a feature of `bootstrap.js`. This is the out from `sudo docker run -it -p 8000:8000 dockerized_site`:

```
Starting Gunicorn.
[2017-06-07 00:38:56 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
[2017-06-07 00:38:56 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
[2017-06-07 00:38:56 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2017-06-07 00:38:56 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
[2017-06-07 00:38:56 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
[2017-06-07 00:38:56 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
Not Found: /js/bootstrap.min.js
Not Found: /js/jquery.js
Not Found: /js/bootstrap.min.js
Not Found: /favicon.ico
```

I appended the static file url pattern to `urls.py`, I am pretty sure this has to do with the container build, or perhaps `settings.py`. Perhaps I need to add an environment directory for the static files? Any help is, of course, appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post the error that gunicorn raises?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your problem:

Your `css`'s are working ok:

```
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Your `js`'s are not working (404):

```
<script src="{% static '/js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
```

See the difference?

The leading `/` in the path of the /js

This fixes your issue:

```
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
```

I cloned your repo and fixed the templates and I've gotten to fix your problem. Please, fix the other `<script>`s

Comment: Thanks again! I've corrected it and pushed to master.

Answer (score 1):

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/deployment/
for static files deployment.

But you may want to serve your static files using a web server like Nginx or Apache. You should not use Gunicorn to serve static files particularly in production. Gunicorn is a WSGI server made for dynamic content.

Comment: In this case the static files deployed until dockerizing the app. I will use Nginx eventually, I am only testing right now.